# Iteration for Jquery object

Tags: jquery

I have a following object :

```
<li class="departure-details">
 <ul>
   <li class="departure"> 
     <span class="departure-date">Wed 07/13/16</span>
     <span class="departure-time">11:12</span>
  </li>
  <li class="arrival">
    <span class="arrival-date">Wed 07/13/16 </span>
    <span class="arrival-time">11:12</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li class="departure"> 
     <span class="departure-date">Wed 07/13/16</span>
     <span class="departure-time">11:12</span>
  </li>
  <li class="arrival">
    <span class="arrival-date">Wed 07/13/16 </span>
    <span class="arrival-time">11:12</span>
  </li>
</ul>
</li>
```

I want to iterate this using jQuery .each function. Please help. Thank in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to SO :) What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
$(function(){
    $("ul li").find("span").each(function() {
       console.log($(this).text()); // loop through all li and print text of span
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="departure-details">
 <ul>
   <li class="departure"> 
     <span class="departure-date">Wed 07/13/16</span>
     <span class="departure-time">11:12</span>
  </li>
  <li class="arrival">
    <span class="arrival-date">Wed 07/13/16 </span>
    <span class="arrival-time">11:12</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li class="departure"> 
     <span class="departure-date">Wed 07/13/16</span>
     <span class="departure-time">11:12</span>
  </li>
  <li class="arrival">
    <span class="arrival-date">Wed 07/13/16 </span>
    <span class="arrival-time">11:12</span>
  </li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$(".departure-details ul").each(function() {// code here});
```